# Trying to find non-overlapping substrings that contain a specific subsequence

Tags: python, regex

I know that there are different ways to do this, but I just want to know why my regex isn't working.  This isn't actually something that I need to do, I just wanted to see if I could do this with a regex, and I have no idea why my code isn't working.

Given a string S, I want to find all non-overlapping substrings that contain a subsequence Q that obeys certain rules.  Now, let's suppose that I am searching for the subsequence `"abc"`.  I want to match a substring of S that contains `'a'` followed at some point by `'b'` followed at some point by `'c'` with the restriction that no `'a'` follows `'a'`, and no `'a'` or `'b'` follows `'b'`.  The regex I am using is as follows (in python):

```
regex = re.compile(r'a[^a]*?b[^ab]*?c')
match = re.finditer(regex, string)

for m in match:
    print m.group(0)
```

To me this breaks down and reads as follows:

`a[^a]*?b`: `'a'` followed the smallest # of characters not including `'a'` and terminating with a `'b'` 
`[^ab]*?c`: the smallest # of characters not including `'a'` or `'b'` and terminating with a `'c'`

So putting this all together, I assumed that I would match non-overlapping substrings of S that contain the subsequence "abc" that obeys my rules of exclusion.

This **works fine** for something like:

`S = "aqwertybwertcaabcc"`, which gives me `"aqwertybwertc"` and `"abc"`,

but it **fails** to work for `S = "abbc"`, as in it matches to `"abbc"`.

Comment: So you don't want it to match `"abbc"`?  But it matches your specifications.

Comment: How I specified that `'b'` cannot be followed by `'a'` or `'b'`?

Comment: You said that the `a` is followed *at some point* by a `b` which is not followed by another `b`, and in `"abbc"`, the second `b` is a `b` after `a` which is not followed by another `b`.  Your specifications never prohibited any `b`s between the `a` and the eventual `b`-not-followed-by-more-`b`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming what you actually want is for the subsequence Q to contain no `a`s between the first `a` and the first `b` and no `a`s or `b`s between the first `b` and the first `c` after the first `b`, the correct regex to use is:

```
r'a[^ab]*b[^abc]*c'
```

The regex that you're currently using will do everything that it can to succeed on a string, including matching the literal `b` to a `b` after the first `b`, which is why `"abbc"` is matched.  Only by specifically excluding `b` in the first character class can this be avoided and the `b` be made to match only the first `b` after the `a`.

Comment: I understand your logic, but I don't see why the non-greedy matching, `*?`, in my regex wouldn't prohibit a `b` following an `a`.  As in I thought that that would take the first `b` following an `a`, and then the next would take the first `c` provided that the characters in between did not include `a` or `b`.

Comment: @SteveP.: Non-greedy just means that it consumes as few characters as possible *while still attempting to successfully match*.  If successfully matching requires consuming an extra character or two, it'll consume an extra character or two.

Comment: Okay, that makes perfect sense.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It could help if you look at the inverse class.
In all cases `abc` is the trivial solution.
And, in this case non-greedy probably doesn't apply because
there are fixed sets of characters used in the example inverse classes.

```
 #  Type 1 :
 #  ( b or c can be between A,B )
 #  ( a or b can be between B,C )
 # ------------------------------
 a                    #  'a'              
 [b-z]*?              #  [^a]
 b                    #  'b'
 [abd-z]*?            #  [^c]
 c                    #  'c'


 #  Type 2, yours :
 #  ( b or c can be between A,B )
 #  ( c can be between B,C )
 # ------------------------------
 a                    #  'a'              
 [b-z]*?              #  [^a]
 b                    #  'b'
 [c-z]*?              #  [^ab]
 c                    #  'c'


 #  Type 3 :
 #  ( c can be between A,B )
 # ------------------------------
 a                    #  'a'              
 [c-z]*?              #  [^ab]
 b                    #  'b'
 [d-z]*?              #  [^abc]
 c                    #  'c'


 #  Type 4 :
 #  ( distinct A,B,C ) :
 # ------------------------------
 a                    #  'a'              
 [d-z]*?              #  [^abc]
 b                    #  'b'
 [d-z]*?              #  [^abc]
 c                    #  'c'
```